# Newton's Law of Cooling Example From Stewart Calculus

Tags: calculus

Why did The line $y(t)=28e^{-0.01663t}$ Change to $T(t)=44+28e^{-0.01663t}$? And why is there a +44?

**Context:** This is an example in a Stewart Calculus Early Transcendentals Textbook 7th ed on Newton's Law of Cooling. (Section 3.8 Page 241) The part I did not understand was when y(t) was changed to T(t). The line $y(t)=28e^{-0.01663t }$ Changed to $T(t)=44+28e^{-0.0166}$

EXAMPLE 3 A bottle of soda pop at room temperature $\left(72^{\circ} \mathrm{F}\right)$ is placed in a refrigerator where the temperature is $44^{\circ} \mathrm{F}$. After half an hour the soda pop has cooled to $61^{\circ} \mathrm{F}$.
(a) What is the temperature of the soda pop after another half hour?
(b) How long does it take for the soda pop to cool to $50^{\circ} \mathrm{F}$ ?
solUTION
(a) Let $T(t)$ be the temperature of the soda after $t$ minutes. The surrounding temperature is $T_{s}=44^{\circ} \mathrm{F}$, so Newton's Law of Cooling states that
$$
\frac{d T}{d t}=k(T-44)
$$
If we let $y=T-44$, then $y(0)=T(0)-44=72-44=28$, so $y$ satisfies
$$
\frac{d y}{d t}=k y \quad y(0)=28
$$
and by (2) we have
$$
y(t)=y(0) e^{k t}=28 e^{k t}
$$
We are given that $T(30)=61$, so $y(30)=61-44=17$ and
$$
28 e^{30 k}=17 \quad e^{30 k}=\frac{17}{28}
$$
Taking logarithms, we have
$$
k=\frac{\ln \left(\frac{17}{28}\right)}{30} \approx-0.01663
$$

Thus
$$
\begin{aligned}
y(t) &=28 e^{-0.01663 t} \\
T(t) &=44+28 e^{-0.01663 t} \\
T(60) &=44+28 e^{-0.01663(60)} \approx 54.3
\end{aligned}
$$
So after another half hour the pop has cooled to about $54^{\circ} \mathrm{F}$.
(b) We have $T(t)=50$ when
$$
\begin{aligned}
44+28 e^{-0.01663 t} &=50 \\
e^{-0.01663 t} &=\frac{6}{28} \\
t &=\frac{\ln \left(\frac{6}{28}\right)}{-0.01663} \approx 92.6
\end{aligned}
$$
The pop cools to $50^{\circ} \mathrm{F}$ after about 1 hour 33 minutes.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 1):

because in the solution, we let $y(t)=T(t)-44$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).